# Ranking of a tuple in another table

Tags: sql, vertica

So I have 2 tables, team A and team B, with their score. I want the rank of the score of every member of team A within team B using SQL or vertica, as shown below

```
 Team A Table

user   score
-------------   
asa      100        
bre      200     
cqw      50      
duy      50      




Team B Table

user   score 
------------  
gfh      20       
ewr      80     
kil      70      
cvb      90
```

Output:

```
Team A Table

user   score   rank in team B
------------------------------ 
asa      100     1   
bre      200     1
cqw      50      4
duy      50      4
```

Comment: To me, it looks like that independent ranking with table a would produce the exact same result. Can you choose some different data for example? also, how cqw got 3 and duy got 4 rank? shouldn't they be ranked equally? Are using the user column too for ranking?

Comment: @gurv Yes it was a mistake, I fixed the values, is it clear now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - and this only works in Vertica.

`INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE` is an outer-join predicate specific to Vertica that joins two tables on non-equal columns, using the 'last known' value in the outer-joined table to make a match succeed.

```
WITH
-- input, don't use in query itself
table_a (the_user,score) AS (
          SELECT 'asa',100        
UNION ALL SELECT 'bre',200     
UNION ALL SELECT 'cqw',50      
UNION ALL SELECT 'duy',50      
)
,
table_b(the_user,score) AS (
          SELECT 'gfh',20       
UNION ALL SELECT 'ewr',80     
UNION ALL SELECT 'kil',70      
UNION ALL SELECT 'cvb',90
)
-- end of input - start WITH clause here
,
ranked_b AS (
SELECT
  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC) AS the_rank
, *
FROM table_b
)
SELECT
  a.the_user AS a_user
, a.score    AS a_score
, b.the_rank AS rank_in_team_b
FROM table_a  a
LEFT JOIN ranked_b b
  ON a.score INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE b.score
ORDER BY 1
;

a_user|a_score|rank_in_team_b
asa   |    100|             1
bre   |    200|             1
cqw   |     50|             4
duy   |     50|             4
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Simple correlated query should do:

```
select 
    a.*,
    (select count(*) + 1 from table_b b where b.score > a.score) rank_in_b
from table_a a;
```

All you need to do is count the number of people with more score than current user in the table b and add 1 to it to get the rank.

Comment: Does not work in Vertica .... `executing statement returns SQL_ERROR:
0A000:1:4160:ERROR 4160:  Non-equality correlated subquery expression is not supported`